# White, green, blue, purple javaScript elements in Repl: what are they?

Tags: javascript, read-eval-print-loop

I'm learning to code javaScript. The arguments I type are displayed in different colors. I know that the colors signify the type of element I just entered (string, conditional, etc.). But I don't know what element types correspond to each color. Is there a legend somewhere that says:

- purple elements === conditional
- green elements ==== string

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Which repl are you using? It's different for every implementation. If you're looking for documentation on this, look into the documentation of the tool you are using.